# Oracle10g- Replace multiple carriage return

Tags: sql, oracle, carriage-return

a query returns string like `AAA[][]AAA[][][][]BBB[][]BBB` . I need to replace the four consecutive carriage returns with a semicolon but not the consecutive two carriage returns. I have tried

```
replace(STRING,chr(13)||chr(13)||chr(13)||chr(13),';')
```

but it has no effect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the ascii codes of the four characters you think are carriage returns, like so:  `select ascii(substring(STRING,9,1)), ascii(substring(STRING,10,1)), ascii(substring(STRING,11,1)), ascii(substring(STRING,12,1)) from`...

Comment: With "carriage return" do you mean **two** characters, i.e. the "line end" in Windows composed of two characters with the ASCII values 13 and 10 or only one single character - the actual carriage return with the ASCII value of 13?

Comment: To show the character values of a string use the dump function: select dump(string) from ...

Comment: This question was also posted on OTN. The solution is that the "four carriage returns" are *not* four carriage returns but actually Windows line feeds i.e. CHR(13)||CHR(10). https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10856939#10856939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CHR(10)` on linux/unix systems. On Windows, the carriage returns are composed of two characters `CHR(10)||chr(13)`. On linux:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT 'AAA
  3  
  4  AAA
  5  
  6  
  7  
  8  BBB
  9  
 10  BBB' txt FROM dual
 11  ) SELECT replace(txt, chr(10)||chr(10)||chr(10)||chr(10), ';') rep
 12      FROM DATA;

REP
------------------------------
AAA

AAA;BBB

BBB
```

Since you you can use newlines directly in expressions, you can make it work on all platforms/character sets with newline characters (I would recommend this solution since it's portable):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT 'AAA
  3  
  4  AAA
  5  
  6  
  7  
  8  BBB
  9  
 10  BBB' txt FROM dual
 11  ) SELECT replace(txt, '
 12  
 13  
 14  
 15  ', ';') rep FROM DATA;

REP
--------------------------
AAA

AAA;BBB

BBB
```

Comment: It was a chr(13)||chr(10) combination